# Laravel Relationship with integer[] type of postgresql column

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, relation

I have `categories` table and `products` table. in `products` table have `category_id` column type of `integer[]`.

> ex: {1,2,3}

.

And I need `products` list with `category` relation which `categories.id` exist `products.category_id`

I tried in model `Product`:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, \DB::raw("ANY(category_id)"), 'id');
}
```

no get `category is null`.

Comment: This is not an answer, but I recommend that you never store foreign keys in an array. Not only will your queries become complicated and slow, but you cannot enforce referential integrity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't relation but with attribute i can get categories

firstly cast category_id to array and

```
public function getCategoriesAttribute()
{
    return Category::whereIn('id',$this->category_id)->get();
}
```

and it works

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I dont think it's possible to do this with the Laravel Relationship Methods.

Second of all, if you are using Postgres, which is a relational Database, you should definitely read up on the fundamentals of database normalization.

I would recommend you have a so called pivot table, that links your products to your categories, which could look something like this:

*Disclaimer: You dont need to create a Model for this. Just make a migration with `php artisan make:migration create_categories_products_table`*

`categories_products`

```
|         id          |     category_id  |      product_id     |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          55         |         1        |          5          |
|          56         |         2        |          5          |
|          57         |         3        |          5          |
|          58         |         1        |          6          |
```

This table links your tables and this is much more easy to handle than some arrays stored as json.. maybe think about it, it is not that much work to do. You can read upon it on the Laravel Documentation or try searching on google for pivot tables and normalization.

### When you have done that:

Now you can just use the Laravel `belongsToMany` Relationship like so:

```php
// Product.php
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'categories_products');
}
```

```php
// Category.php
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'categories_products');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use belongs to many relation.
because integer[] type is for saving arrays of ints.
try to set it in your  model like this:

in your `Product(model)` you will get this relation method:

```
public function categories(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

And in your `Category(model)`:

```
public function products(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

[Refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58706027/5257498)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using laravel query builder

```
public function category()
{
 return DB::table('products')
 ->join('categories', 'products.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
 ->get();
}
```